# Can I make my kendo-grid-column width size based on the header content?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, angular6

I have an Angular 6 application that I am building and I am using kendo-grid for some table data.  Everything works great except that the column headers are "too long" and are cut to ellipsis on my desktop.  Is there a way to wrap the text of the header or to make the column width be based on the column header text.  I can make the width fixed, but I would like to avoid doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either overwrite the default styling via CSS to wrap the content, e.g.:

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
styles: [`
  .k-grid .k-header {
    white-space: normal;

  }
`]
```

[EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bhysva?file=app/app.component.ts)

... or use the autoFitColumns() method after the Grid is rendered:

[EXAMPLE](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui-develop/components/grid/columns/resizing/#toc-auto-fitting-content)